# why is my my class giving me an error for the return?

Tags: java, class

Now i got it set as a constructor, however I am unsure how to actually use this. I want to be able to store the first name, last name and degree level. I need it to continue to run until I stop it and continue with more of the program.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.ArrayList; 

public class Tutor
{
public Tutor(String firstName, String firstName, String degreeLevel)
    {
    firstName = firstName;
    lastName = firstName;
    degreeLevel = degreeLevel;  
    }   
public static void main (String[] args)
    {
    String fName;
    String lName;
    String level;
    String ans;
    ArrayList<String> listOfTutor = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i<listOfTutor.size(); i++)
        {
        fName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter Tutor's First Name: ");
        lName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter Tutor's Last Name: ");
        level = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter Tutor's Highest Level of Degree: ");
        Tutor t = new Tutor(fName,lName,level);
        listOfTutor.add(t);
        }
    }   
}
```

**Edit**

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.ArrayList; 

public class Tutor
{
String firstName;
String lastName;
String degreeLevel;
public Tutor(String firstName, String lastName, String degreeLevel)
    {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = firstName;
    this.degreeLevel = degreeLevel; 
    }   
public static void main (String[] args)
    {
    String fName;
    String lName;
    String level;
    String ans;
    ArrayList<Tutor> listOfTutor = new ArrayList<Tutor>();
    for (int i = 0; i<3; i++)
        {
        fName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter Tutor's First Name: ");
        lName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter Tutor's Last Name: ");
        level = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter Tutor's Highest Level of Degree: ");
        Tutor t = new Tutor(fName,lName,level);
        listOfTutor.add(t);
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: You need to specify a Returntype, in your example it should be String. `public static String Tutor(...)`

Comment: Rename your class to match the constructor, and remove the `return` statment.

Comment: You should learn basic concepts of Java programming first...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did a lot of wrong there:

First: If Tutor is a Method:

You have to set a Return Type to your Method. `public static String Tutor(...)`
This way your Method returns your values correctly.

Second: If Tutor should be your Class:

Then you have to rename either your class to Tutor or your Constructor to CalculateATutor.
A constructor never has a Return Type and never contains a return-Statement. So this way you have to delete your return-Statement in your Constructor.

```
public CalculateATutor(String firstName, String lastName, String degreeLevel)
{
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.degreeLevel = degreeLevel; 
}
```

Third:

The usage of your Class Tutor (if it is a class) is wrong

```
String ans;
List<Tutor> myTutor = new ArrayList<Tutor>(); //You have to specify Tutor in your Template-Class
for (int i = 0; i<myTutor.size; i++)
    {
    ans = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter Tutor's Last Name, First Name, and Highest Level of Degree:");
    //Here you have a lot to do because you get one inputstring with all 3 Elements
    //You have to split the input or get 3 seperate inputs
    // We assume you have your correct input here right now with Strings fname, lname, level
    Tutor t = new Tutor(lname,fname,level);
    myTutor.add(t);
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
To your new Question:

You have to declare local variables into the class.

```
public class TestClass{
    String lastName;

    public TestClass(String lastName){// this is the Constructor
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

}
```

This way you can store the Variables.

Comment: i get this error and I am unsure what this means:
   Tutor.java:28: error: no suitable method found for add(Tutor)
   listOfTutor.add(t);

Comment: Well your code is pretty much right. The only thing missing is the local Variable in the class. Read my example TestClass and you'll see how to store the variables. The Variable-declaration has to be out of the Methods. (Out of the main-function and out of the constructor. In the constructor you only set the variable as shown in my example). And watch your constructor. You have to parameters with the same name. Change this please.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but no. its saying the strings are already defined now, and It still gives me the `error: no suitable method found for add(Tutor)
   listOfTutor.add(t);`

Comment: For your add-Problem. Change your List from `List<String> listOfTutor = new ArrayList<String>();` to `List<Tutor> listOfTutor = new ArrayList<Tutor>();`

Comment: Can you update your code after the List<Tutor>-Change on your question again, please.

Answer (score 3):

You need getting the error because the `Tutor()` function is returning a value, but no return type is given in the method declaration.

If you want your function to return a String:

```
public String Tutor(String firstName, String lastName, String degreeLevel)
       ^^^^^^
```

There are actually many problems in the code currently. I believe what you're trying to do is make Tutor() a constructor. If that's the case, it's declaration should be:

```
public CalculateATutor(String firstName, String lastName, String degreeLevel)
```

because CalculateATutor is the name of the class. It should not return anything. Additionally, these lines:

```
this.firstName = firstName;
this.lastName = lastName;
this.degreeLevel = degreeLevel;
```

will not work the way you want. If you're attempting to set class fields, you need to declare the fields in your class first. Like this:

```
public class CalculateATutor
{
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    String degreeLevel; 
    ...
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `public static String Tutor` (because main-Function is in the same class and there the Method is called)

Comment: @Loki Yeah I'm actually not too sure what's supposed to be going on here now. It seems like Tutor is possibly supposed to be a constructor. Hmm

Answer (score 2):

```
public String Tutor(String firstName, String lastName, String degreeLevel)
       ^ missing
```

as you are returning String

```
return(lastName +", "+ firstName +" "+ degreeLevel);
```

Instead our answers try to understand **compiler's error message:**

```
 error: invalid method declaration; return type required
                      ^ function declaration is wrong
```

Also says `return type required`   So you forgot return type of function.

Where function name is  `public Tutor()`

Answer (score 1):

Add return type to method. As you posted you are returning String without giving return type of method. So add String as return type of method.

If you try to return a value from a method that is declared void, you will get a compiler error.

```
public String Tutor(String firstName, String lastName, String degreeLevel) {
  .....
   return(lastName +", "+ firstName +" "+ degreeLevel);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're treating `Tutor` like a method. If `Tutor` is indeed a method, you don't have a return type associated with it.

Also where are `firstName`, `lastName`, and `degreeLevel` getting declared at in the class? It looks to me like there maybe other issues than just that -- keep in mind.

Answer (score 1):

```
public Tutor(String firstName, String lastName, String degreeLevel)
```

should be

```
public String Tutor(String firstName, String lastName, String degreeLevel)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is really messed.
You have a class named `CalculateATutor`, inside it something looks like a constructor but named `Tutor` and you use it inside your `main` function as a regular class.

**First, you need to understand what you want to do** (and maybe read about [classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/class.html) and [constructors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html)).

But for your question:

If you want to have a method named Tutor, you need to add return type to the method signature;

```
public String Tutor(String firstName, String lastName, String degreeLevel)
    {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.degreeLevel = degreeLevel; 
    return(lastName +", "+ firstName +" "+ degreeLevel);
    }
```

If you're trying to create a constructor, you need to use the class name and remove the return statement:

```
public CalculateATutor(String firstName, String lastName, String degreeLevel)
    {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.degreeLevel = degreeLevel; 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message is telling you what to do. all Java methods/functions have to be declared with a return type.

In this case it appears to be a String, so it becomes

```
public String Tutor()
```

If you dont want it to return anything then it is

```
public void getMiau()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Tutor method is returning a string, but you haven't declared it as having a return type. Try:

```
public String Tutor(String firstName, String lastName, String degreeLevel)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear if `Tutor` is supposed to be a method or a constructor. If it is supposed to be a constructor, you are declaring it in a class named `CalculateATutor`, which won't work. You also did not write the constructor as a constructor (it should not have a `return` statement). You can fix this in several ways:

1. Change the class name to `Tutor`.
2. Change the constructor name to `CalculateATutor`.
3. Move the `Tutor` constructor to an inner class of `CalculateATutor` named `Tutor`.

Comment: But then also delete the return-statement in the "Constructor"

Comment: @Loki - good point! I updated my wording to account for this.

Answer (score 0):

1) you're using the this. keywork to refer to class variables that you haven't defined
2) you seem to have called the class CalculateATutor but the constructor for the class Tutor, they should be the same, so something like this:

import javax.swing.*;

```
public class Tutor //NOTE CORRECTED CLASS NAME
{
String firstName;
String lastName;
String degreeLevel
public Tutor(String firstName, String lastName, String degreeLevel)
    {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.degreeLevel = degreeLevel; 

    }   
public static void main (String[] args)
    {
    String ans;
    List<Tutor> Tutor = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i<Tutor.size; i++) //Tutor.size==0, will never run, I can't correct as I have no idea what you want to happen
        {
        ans = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter Tutor's Last Name, First Name, and Highest Level of Degree:");
        Tutor = ans; //I have no idea whats going on here but Tutor should be initialised like new Tutor(string,string,string)

        }
    }   
}
```